# pymongo 4.1.1 and mongoengine version compatibility

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Updated to pymongo 4.1.1 and upgraded mongoengine to 0.24.1 but received the following error:

```
pymongo/collection.py", line 1610, in find
    return Cursor(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword 
argument 'modifiers'
```

I was under the impression the latest versions would work together. Are they not compatible? The error appears in pymongo itself and not in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `pymongo` error seems to come from a removed option.

From the [`pymongo` API docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find):

> Changed in version 4.0: Removed the modifiers option. Empty
> projections (eg {} or []) are passed to the server as-is, rather than
> the previous behavior which substituted in a projection of {"_id": 1}.
> This means that an empty projection will now return the entire
> document, not just the "_id" field.

In addition, currently (2022-05-04) there seem to be several [`pymongo >= 4.0` issues](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+pymongo) against the `mongoengine` codebase.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out rickhg12hs, I missed it. That means the issue is not related to the mongoengine in this case. I was able to resolve the issue by removing a modifiers parameter in a find. I would vote you up but my reputation is not high enough yet to vote.